# Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing discord.js react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discord.js

**i can discord oauth2 typescript & react But I am confronted with this error. I don't know how to solve it. Could you please help?
It constantly renews me at the address I entered, please help me about this topic.**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom"
    import fetch from "node-fetch";
    
    import NavigationBar from "./navigation/NavigationBar";
    import ServerSelection from "../pages/ServerSelection";
    
    export default class App extends Component {
        state = {
            loading: true,
            user: null
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            fetch("http://192.168.1.34:8080/oauth/details", {
                credentials: "include"
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => {
                    if (!res) return this.setState({ loading: false });
                    this.setState({
                        loading: false,
                        user: res
                    })
            })
            .catch(() => this.setState({ loading: false }));
        }
    
        render() {
            if (this.state.loading) {
                return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <div className="container">
                            <h1>Loading...</h1>
                        </div>
                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            } else if (!this.state.user) {
                window.location.replace("http://192.168.1.34:8080/oauth/login");
```

Comment: Read the error console, it said nothing was returned from render. In your else if statement, you should return something too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by your render() method not returning any component.

You have an if and else-if blocks in your render method, but what if both conditions fail? you render() method should have a final return statement or an else block.

The error is caused by this line:

```
.catch(() => this.setState({ loading: false }));
```

So when your fetch encounters and error, it sets loading to false, then when your compoenent tries to render, this happens:

```
if (this.state.loading)
```

loading is false so that condition fails

```
this.setState({
                    loading: false,//loading was set to false
                    user: res
                })
```

this condition also fails because you have assigned a value to the state.user

```
.then(res => {
                    if (!res) return this.setState({ loading: false });
                    this.setState({
                        loading: false,
                        user: res//user is also not falsey
                    })
```

The solution is to add a final return statement:

```
render() {
            if (this.state.loading) {
                return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <div className="container">
                            <h1>Loading...</h1>
                        </div>
                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            } else if (!this.state.user) {
                window.location.replace("http://192.168.1.34:8080/oauth/login");
                return <p>EMPTY USER</p>;
            }
            return <p>CONDITIONS FAILED</p>;
       }
```